# Switch with string patterns

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm trying to use `Switch` to process lines from a text file. I know that

```
StringMatchQ["abc", "a"~~___]
```

evaluates to `True`, and

```
Switch["abc", "a"~~"bc", 1, _, 2]
```

evaluates to `1`

but why does the following evaluate to `2`?

```
Switch["abc", "a"~~___, 1, _, 2]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Switch` doesn't use the form of the first argument to somehow predict what kind of comparison you want to do. So, it doesn't automatically try a string match just because you passed in the string "abc". And since the expression `"a" ~~ ___` is a `StringExpression`, and `"abc"` is not a `StringExpression`, but just a string, then the first match fails.

In the case of

```
Switch["abc", "a"~~"bc", 1, _, 2]
```

The expression `“a”~~”bc”` actually evaluates to just `“abc”`, so you get an exact match.

You could do this:

```
Switch["abc", _String?(StringMatchQ["a" ~~ ___]), 1, _, 2]
```

or just:

```
Switch["abc", _?(StringMatchQ["a" ~~ ___]), 1, _, 2]
```

Or you could use `Which`.

Comment: Thank you @lericr, great clarity!